# Handling aborted requests in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Say I have the following action

```
public async TaskIActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
    // do something with form contents
}
```

and it's called with a large, say 100MB, file.

How can I handle what happens when a user cancels/aborts the request? (e.g it's uploaded 50MB and user stops the request) Is there a way to detect this? Is this even a valid question to be asking?

Comment: IIRC, there's a `CancellationToken` on the `Controller.Request` object which allows you to know if the request has been cancelled.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto there's `HttpContext.RequestAborted`?

Comment: Hmm, apparently that is for server-side triggering, I think what I want is to know when the client disconnects.

Comment: OH in ASP.NET Core 2.0.0 `RequestAborted` will be triggered on client disconnects. https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/197#issuecomment-279129671

Comment: @Mardoxx You could make that an answer :)

Comment: You can add the `CancellationToken` to your action signature and ASP.NET Core MVC will pass it automatically to you. I'm not sure if it's all hooked up to respond to dropped connections, but that's the *intended* solution, at least.

Comment: @StephenCleary amazing, thanks! Got any documentation on that?

Comment: Looks like the docs have all changed since I read that. Closest I could find is [how `CancellationToken` is treated during model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding).

Comment: Just to update you on this, RequestAborted now fires in 2.0 when the client disconnects.